# Check if cache cid exist

Tags: 8, caching

I have this code:

```
$cache = \Drupal::cache();
$result = $cache->get('tdcf_00SPH46T');
```

Then, I got this notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tdcf_00SPH46T in Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend->getMultiple() (line 92 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/DatabaseBanckend.php).
Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend->getMultiple(Array, ) Line: 63
Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend->get('tdcf_00SPH46T')_(Line: 46)
...
```

Is any way for check if this cid is defined, for example:

```
$cache->has('tdcf_00SPH46T');
```

Answer (score 1):

What database backend are you using? Sounds like a case problem, that a cache entry with a different upper/lower case version exists and then it can't map that back. I'd suggest using only lowercase but this shouldn't happen IMHO and it doesn't for me:

```
>>> $cache = \Drupal::cache();
=> Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend {#48
     +"_serviceId": "cache.default",
   }
>>> $cache->get('foo');
=> false
>>> $cache->set('foo', 'bar');
=> null
>>> $cache->get('foo');
=> {#9809
     +"cid": "foo",
     +"data": "bar",
     +"created": "1505412278.945",
     +"expire": "-1",
     +"serialized": "0",
     +"tags": [],
     +"checksum": "0",
     +"valid": true,
   }
>>> $cache->get('Foo');
=> false
```